# All or both in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Which one of the following is correct?

1) Its strong faculty and motivated students are **all** appealing to me.

2) Its strong faculty and motivated students are **both** appealing to me.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest neither: _Its strong faculty and motivated students are appealing to me._

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: *"Its strong faculty and motivated students are appealing to me."* gets the message across just fine.

Having said that, *both* sounds more idiomatic, although I would change the word order a bit:

*"Both its strong faculty and motivated students are appealing to me."*